assigning pattern matches in an if statement
I have to move to Lua for a scripting language and trying to recreate a condition I use a lot

line 1: if the pattern returns capture groups, assign them to "match" and this condition returns true

regFind is my function that runs pattern matches and returns the matches as a python dictionary


line 2: if true, then use the capture group values


is this even possible in Lua?
thanks so much for your help
1. if (match := o.regFind("(?P<test>\d+)\s(?P<letters>[A-Z]+)","1111111 GGGG")):
2.    if match["test"]:
3.        value = match.get("test")
4.        print(value)
5.    if match["letters"] != None:
6.        print(match)

I created a lua function called "Regex" that will return the capture matches as a table. But this gets a syntax error because it's expecting ==
if matches = Regex("THIS IS a TEST", "%a") then
  print "is a match"
end


I did not realize python let you do an assignment inside of a if condition, but no lua does not allow that.

You can not do an assignment inside an if condition in lua.
I dont really see the point, you could just run the function and assignment before your if condition.
local matches = Regex("THIS IS a TEST", "%a") 
if matches then
  print "is a match"
end

If you are so inclined to keep that flow, you could have your regex function save to some global variable and then return true or false, or you could have it store the data internally to avoid the global.
local regex = {
    matches = {}
}
local mt = {
    match = function(self, str, pattern)
        found = false
        for w in string.gmatch(str, pattern) do
            self.matches[w] = true; -- or like whatever you want to do here.
            found = true
        end
       return found
    end
}
mt.__index = mt
setmetatable(regex, mt)

if (regex:match("THIS IS a TEST", "%a"))then
  print("is a match")
end


"I dont really see the point" - the point of "if let" variants is to have the variable's scope be exactly the if statement (e.g. to prevent accidental use of the variable outside the if). This is a bit more tedious to do in Lua (you'd have to use do local match = ... if match then ... end end).
